# The text of [a person's name]

Tags: meaning, phrases

> when, with Griesbach [the Greek text of J. J. Griesbach] in my hand, I
> read over every verse in Chinese, and suggest my doubts relative to
> the force of particular characters, rejecting some, and suggesting
> others.

From the context, this probably means the Greek text written by J.J.Griesbach. So "something of some person" can sometimes mean "something done by some person"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google finds a bible scholar with this name.

Comment: [Johann Jakob Griesbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Jakob_Griesbach)

Comment: JJ Griesbach is certainly one of the first results if you search for "Griesbach". It also helps when asking a question to say where you encountered the phrase, and to provide some of the surrounding text. It's obviously a reference to Griesbach's Bible study, but it's not clear precisely what is referred to by the phrase - in particular, is there an implicit contrast to some other version of the NT? Absent a source, we have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking why "with Griesbach in my hand" refers to holding the text that Griesbach wrote, rather than holding the person Griesbach.

This is an example of [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy). The person is referenced when talking about something they produced. This particular form is common in academia. Perhaps it's just laziness, but people often use an author's name to refer to a particular text they wrote.

Comment: This is quite common in many academic and other literate disciplines.